# When calling .predict() I am getting ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, svm

I am still relatively new to the world of data science and I cannot figure out why I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 73, in <module>
    print(classifyAnswer(getAnswer(f_content)))
  File "main.py", line 67, in classifyAnswer
    SVM_predict = loaded_model.predict([array_answer])
  File "C:\Users\A144995\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 574, in predict
    y = super().predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\A144995\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 322, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\A144995\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 454, in _validate_for_predict
    accept_large_sparse=False)
  File "C:\Users\A144995\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 496, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\A144995\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No'
```

The model that is being read was fitted and modeled without any issues, but when I go to classify a sample text (read from a text file into a string) I get the error. The code I am executing is below:

```
f = open("samplechat.txt", 'r')
f_content = f.read()
f.close()

def questionFound(txt):

    x = re.search("(d|D)oes anyone in the household have (l|L)ife (s|S)upport or (m|M)edical (d|D)evices", str(txt))

    return x

def findAgentName(txt):

    return 0

def getAnswer(txt):

    x = re.search("((d|D)oes anyone in the household have (l|L)ife (s|S)upport or (m|M)edical (d|D)evices (that|which) depend (upon|on) supply\?)( *\[Read])( [\w+/g(,|\s)]+)([\d]+\s[\w]+\W\s[\d]+ [,]) ([\d]+:[\d]+[AM|PM|am|pm]+)\s([\w]+)", str(txt))

    return x.group(13)

def classifyAnswer(answer):

    array_answer = [answer]

    classifier = 'webchatls.sav'

    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(classifier, 'rb'))

    SVM_predict = loaded_model.predict([array_answer])

    result = SVM_predict[0]

    return result

print(classifyAnswer(getAnswer(f_content)))
```

I'm still new to this so any guidance in debugging this would be great!

Comment: How exactly was the model trained and fitted? I assume words have been encoded numerically?

Comment: @pavel I never encoded my strings in the training set to numerical values (if we are talking about the use of LabelEncoder() for example). The data was read from a CSV, split into training and test data, vectorized using TfidfVectorizer and then fitted.

Comment: So, the TfidVectorizer converted your training text into a sparse matrix which was used to train the classifier. To predict you also need to give it a sparse matrix.

Comment: You need to pickle the trained instance of Vectorizer that was used to transform training data, then you need to apply it to your classification word(s) and then use trained classifier on the transformed data.

Comment: Thanks @pavel, got it working! I pickled my vectorizer and then instead of using fit_transform(), I just used transform() and it worked!